# Why is Clockworkmod taking up so much memory?

Tags: internal-storage, clockworkmod-recovery

Question: I was checking the memory storage and found that under miscellaneous, Clockworkmod took up 4.5GB of memory. Is that normal? I’m operating on a HC 3.1 3G 10.1 Tab. with 16GB only. Now I have 4GB left. The rest of the other files are less than 50MB.
Please advise.

Comment: Is it a backup that's taking up all that space? Do you have 4GB or so of data (music, photos, etc) on your device?

Comment: Check your backups in /sdcard/clockworkmod/backup. It sounds like you have a lot of backups in there.

Comment: @eldarerathis, Ryan, one of you should probably post that as an answer :)

Answer (score 7):

I would check your `/sdcard/clockworkmod/backup` folder and remove any old backups you have in there.

You can also remove them from within Rom Manager under `Manage and Restore Backups`. Then click on the older backups and select `Delete` from the menu.